# Insert "invalid" content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following constellation:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
</dt>
```

And I want to achieve the following without editing the source code:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Content</dt>
    <dd>123</dd>
</dt>
```

I tried the following jQuery:

```
$('dd:not(:last-child)').after($('</dl><dl>'));
```

The problem is, that jQuery seems to correct the code by itself and thus enters `<dl></dl>` instead of `</dl><dl>`.
Is there any possibility to insert this "invalid" code, which will be valid in the context of the page?

Comment: When doing client-side changes to the page, you're not splicing HTML markup. You're manipulating a DOM that was created from the original HTML markup. So you don't insert HTML fragments to break up elements. You create new elements, insert them into the DOM, and insert existing elements inside them. So in your case, create two new `dl` elements, add them after the existing `dl`, and then relocate the existing `dt,dd` pairs in to the new `dl`s.

Comment: Modifying DOM and modifying HTML are two completely different things. `.after` will modify DOM. If you have to directly modify HTML (which you should never do it), use `.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/6cNNS/

```
$('dd').each(function(){
    $(this).prev('dt').andSelf().wrapAll($('<dl></dl>'));
});
$('dl:first').after($('dl:first').children());
$('dl:first').remove();
```

Comment: Note, if jQuery 1.8 or later is used, then `.addBack()` should be used instead of `.andSelf()`, which was deprecated.